# If H×K⊴ G, K⊴G, then H⊴G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If H×K⊴ G, K⊴G, then H⊴G?

My attempt: Let G act on H×K by conjugation and obtain family of induced automorphism. Since K⊴G, there is a very strict requirement for what these automorphism map the K to. However, I can't prove that it is impossible. I can't come up with counter example either.

Note, I am not sure if the statement of the problem is correct as I only recall it from memory. I kinda remember I proved it before but could not reprove it. If the statement is wrong, please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true.

Let $G = D_8$, the dihedral group of the square. Let $a$ be rotation by $\pi/2$, and let $b$ be a reflection.

Then $\langle a \rangle$ has index 2, hence is normal in $G$. Since $\langle a \rangle$ is cyclic, its subgroup $K = \langle a^2 \rangle$ is characteristic in $\langle a \rangle$, hence normal in $G$.

Let $H = \langle b \rangle$.

Since $K$ is normal in $G$, $HK$ is a subgroup. Moreover, $H \cap K = 1$ and $|HK| = |H||K|/|H \cap K| = 4$. Thus $H$ has index $2$ in $HK$, so $H$ is normal in $HK$. Therefore $HK$ is a direct product.

Moreover, $HK$ has index $2$ in $G$, so $HK$ is normal in $G$.

But $H$ is not normal in $G$, because e.g. $aba^{-1} = a^2b \neq b$.